# Clone Windows partition to 60GB SSD

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, ssd, data-migration

(I have Ubuntu and Windows on my HDD but only want Windows on my SSD)

So I got a 60GB SSD and while my entire C: partition is only about 25GB in size I want to clone C: to the new SSD and be able to boot from it.

I tried `dd if=/dev/sda2 of=/dev/sdb1` but when trying to mount it just gave me an error message. I then tried copying all files from C: to the SSD using rsync, making a new 250MB partition and `dd`ing the drive to the SSD. When using the EFI file for Windows on the SSD I just get an error message from my BIOS.

My C: drive is too big to make an img file and just restore it on my SSD.

---

**Summary:**

I have a 250GB C: drive (HDD) with Windows and Ubuntu

and an empty 60GB SSD

I want to boot Windows from my SSD

`dd if=/path/to/c_drive of=/path/to/ssd` didn't work

`rsync` for NTFS file system and img restoration for EFI partition didn't work either

Making an img file of my C drive and applying it to the SSD won't work because C drive is 250GB and SSD only 60GB

Comment: You want a clonezilla Live-CD

Comment: You need to either resize your windows partition(s) to fit the new drive first or use a tool like Clonezilla or Macrium Reflect to resize the partition for you.